# Como eliminar labels e eixo x em um gráfico de barras invertidas?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Gostaria de saber **como apagar os labels e a linha do eixo X, do seguinte gráfico de barras invertido**. [image: grafico de barras invertido].

É que acho que tem informação redundante.
dados
Oi Lucas, obrigado pela resposta. Segue os dados,

L   log se  padj    sig sigpositiv  signegativ
PZC75086    0.934   0.237   0.00    0
XP_021188570    0.336   0.155   0.22    0
XP_021191392    0.709   0.226   0.03    0
XP_021194193    0.739   0.000   0.01    0
XP_021194353    -0.367  0.166   0.20    0
XP_021195235    0.689   0.178   0.00    0
XP_021197617    1.303   0.794   0.45    0
XP_021200097    0.847   0.237   0.01    0
XP_021201453    0.678   0.243   0.06    0
XP_021201454    0.787   0.248   0.02    0
XP_021201455    0.540   0.248   0.21    0
XP_021201456    0.814   0.305   0.08    0
XP_021201457    2.026   0.948   0.23    0
XP_021201458    1.190   0.427   0.06    0
XP_021201459    1.957   0.999   0.30    0
XP_021201460    2.408   1.276   0.34    0
XP_021201465    1.570   1.680   0.77    0
XP_021201466    -0.382  0.309   0.64    0
XP_021201493    0.397   0.195   0.27    0
XP_021201494    0.667   0.236   0.06    0
XP_021201495    0.869   0.286   0.03    0
XP_021201514    0.713   0.319   0.19    0
XP_021201515    -0.005  0.173   1.00    0
XP_021201516    0.443   0.167   0.08    0
XP_021201518    0.277   0.327   0.81    0
XP_021201552    1.414   0.789   0.38    0
XP_021191406    1.665   0.344   6.64E-05    1   *
XP_021191399    2.322   0.724   0.020938003 1   *
XP_021190221    0.869   0.308   0.057657776 0
XP_021189544    -0.537  0.164   0.017594595 0
,

Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
ggplot(dt, aes(L, log, label = L, hjust = hjust)) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = 0),size=3, colour=colour1) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = sigpositiv, y = log+se+0.5), size = 3.0, 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+
  geom_text(aes(label = signegativ, y = log-se-0.5), size = 3.0, 
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+
  labs(x="", y="")+
  geom_col(aes(fill = colour1),  position = "dodge")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=log-se, ymax=log+se), width=.2)+
  scale_fill_manual(labels= c("ns", "*Significat level \n Fold-Change> 1 or < -1"),
                    values= c("black", "blue"))+
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "", y = "Log2 Fold-Change",
       fill=  expression(paste(italic("p<"),"0.05")), 
       position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+
  theme_classic()
```

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2]][2]

Comment: você pode disponilizar os dados ou fazer um MWE?

Comment: Oi Lucas, obrigado pela resposta. Segue os dados,

Comment: Espero que seja de ajuda. Se quiser posso te passar os dados em outro formato!

Answer (score -2):

Gente, consegui, é só adicionar no meio e mudar de theme:
**scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL) +**
**theme(element_line(color = "white"),
panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))**

´´´
ggplot(dt, aes(L, log, label = L, hjust = hjust)) +
geom_text(aes(y = 0),size=3, colour=colour1) +
geom_text(aes(label = sigpositiv, y = log+se+0.5), size = 3.0,
position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+
geom_text(aes(label = signegativ, y = log-se-0.5), size = 3.0,
position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+
labs(x="", y="")+
scale_x_discrete(breaks = NULL) +
geom_col(aes(fill = colour1),  position = "dodge")+
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=log-se, ymax=log+se), width=.2)+
scale_fill_manual(labels= c("ns", "*Significat level \n Fold-Change> 1 or < -1"),
values= c("black", "blue"))+
coord_flip() +
labs(x = "", y = "Log2 Fold-Change",
fill=  expression(paste(italic("p<"),"0.05")),
position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+
theme(element_line(color = "white"),
panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
´´´